# WebRTC in Chrome Can't setLocalDescription Twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm working on setting up an audio only WebRTC connection between a web page Chrome and a node server and I'm having an issue on the Chrome side.  When I first set up the connection, it sets up, exchanges tracks and then immediately renegotiates (which is another whole can of worms...).  I would just ignore this but for some reason when I try to renegotiate, the peerConnection.setLocalDescription call fails with the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setLocalDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set local offer sdp: The order of m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous offer/answer.
```

On the surface this error looks super simple, but when I dig into it there's a problem: I only have one m line in both offers.  Surely a single element can't be out of order.

First Offer (from initial connection):

```
sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 5276320653971578470 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=-
↵t=0 0
↵a=group:BUNDLE 0
↵a=msid-semantic: WMS 7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI
↵m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
↵c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=ice-ufrag:Hh9D
↵a=ice-pwd:ylsBH6R2uYK6CGDp4AeRokmT
↵a=ice-options:trickle
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 6C:17:87:F0:95:E4:22:B3:51:A3:AB:E3:89:97:35:FA:E8:87:03:DE:03:4D:40:48:56:43:47:84:46:C6:F7:99
↵a=setup:actpass
↵a=mid:0
↵a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
↵a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
↵a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
↵a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
↵a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
↵a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=msid:7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI ebf11949-396c-482c-99fb-3ab8ee2831d8
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
↵a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
↵a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
↵a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
↵a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
↵a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
↵a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
↵a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
↵a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
↵a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
↵a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
↵a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
↵a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
↵a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
↵a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
↵a=ssrc:72299041 cname:ppuQRRMMV5kqIwjE
↵a=ssrc:72299041 msid:7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI ebf11949-396c-482c-99fb-3ab8ee2831d8
↵a=ssrc:72299041 mslabel:7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI
↵a=ssrc:72299041 label:ebf11949-396c-482c-99fb-3ab8ee2831d8
↵"
```

Second Offer (from renegotiation):

```
sdp: "v=0
↵o=- 5276320653971578470 3 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
↵s=-
↵t=0 0
↵a=group:BUNDLE 1
↵a=msid-semantic: WMS 7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI
↵m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
↵c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
↵a=ice-ufrag:YKAt
↵a=ice-pwd:hhXt6B+dtCNHB0/VT6m0PU0V
↵a=ice-options:trickle
↵a=fingerprint:sha-256 6C:17:87:F0:95:E4:22:B3:51:A3:AB:E3:89:97:35:FA:E8:87:03:DE:03:4D:40:48:56:43:47:84:46:C6:F7:99
↵a=setup:actpass
↵a=mid:1
↵a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
↵a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
↵a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
↵a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
↵a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
↵a=extmap:6 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
↵a=sendrecv
↵a=msid:7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI ebf11949-396c-482c-99fb-3ab8ee2831d8
↵a=rtcp-mux
↵a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
↵a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
↵a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
↵a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
↵a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
↵a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
↵a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
↵a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
↵a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
↵a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
↵a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
↵a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
↵a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
↵a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
↵a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
↵a=ssrc:562412871 cname:ppuQRRMMV5kqIwjE
↵a=ssrc:562412871 msid:7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI ebf11949-396c-482c-99fb-3ab8ee2831d8
↵a=ssrc:562412871 mslabel:7NP7gF4tCmvRogdXybzgnCM9GUzCQDoogyYI
↵a=ssrc:562412871 label:ebf11949-396c-482c-99fb-3ab8ee2831d8
↵"
```

I've put breakpoints in the code so I can confirm these are the only two places setLocalOffer is being called.  I've tried without any tracks, but then ice negotiation won't start.  I've tried looking this up, but as close as I was able to get was making sure that you aren't trying to negotiate while in the wrong state, and I verified that I'm not.  I'm clearly missing something simple, what is it?

Comment: `I've tried without any tracks, but then ice negotiation won't start` -- you can get around this by doing a DataChannel! Just do a `createDataChannel` on each side, and just don't use it. Sorry not sure of your root issue yet, but that might be helpful.

Comment: Ah.  That would have been easier.  I removed all the tracks from the local side for the time being so there are no m lines in the local description and that does work.  (Which tells me that the problem isn't somehow on my server.)

Comment: It seems a bit counterintuitive but you need to have the `peerConnection.addTrack(track)` calls after the initial `peerConnection.createOffer().then(peerConnection.setLocalDescription)`

Comment: Whoops.  I forgot to come back and answer this.  Turns out the answer was the exact opposite of this.  I was calling the add track after the communication was negotiated, which was causing the renegotiation.
However, the actual problem here was a bug in Chrome that caused renegotiation failures in environments where ICMP was restricted.  Said bug has since been patched.